# How to Build a Json Object by Sending it Part by Part to a File in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json

I'm currently working on a project where I wind up creating a very large JSON dictionary of dictionaries. Keeping this entire object in memory at once would be painful, and since I'm calculating what will go into the dictionary key by key, I was hoping for a way to write each key to the file I'll eventually dump the json to as soon as its value is calculated. This way I'd never need to hold more than one key/value pair in memory at one time, which would be awesome.

The object is of the form:

```
{key: {key: val, key: val, key:val, etc...},
 key: {key: val, key: val, key:val, etc...},
 key: {key: val, key: val, key:val, etc...},
 etc...
}
```

This wouldn't be very hard to do if I just manually printed the beginning and end of the dictionary in JSON along with commas around each JSON subdictionary I print, but I figure there must be a way to do this through one of Python's JSON libraries that's much cleaner. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module loads and dumps entire objects, so you can't do it directly with that. There are event-driven (["SAX style"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)) JSON parsers available, for example [yajl](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/), which has [Python bindings](http://pykler.github.com/yajl-py/).

Personally I try not to use 3rd-party dependencies unless I have to, so I'd probably go with manually printing the beginning/end/keys and using the built-in JSON module. Or just keep the whole thing in memory. How much memory does it actually take? Remember to only optimize once you've profiled and found it to be a problem. :-)